# What is the onclick event of the input submit after validating the form with html5? Problem: nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, nodemailer

I created an email.js module instantiating nodemailer. I was able to send/receive email with gmail normally by running node email.js (with to, for, subject, text already filled in in the code).
At the moment I'm trying to use the submit input from my form to trigger nodemailer (which now needs to access the values of the inputs filled in on the site and send it by email). I can't do this by assigning onclick="Send()" to the form's submit input.

HTML:

```
<section class="sec-form">
            <form name="form_contato" method="post" id="form-block">
                <h1 id="contato">Contato</h1>
                <input type="text" id="nomeid" placeholder="Seu nome" name="nome" required/>
                <input type="email" id="emailid" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required/>
                <input type="text" id="assuntoid" placeholder="Assunto"/>
                <textarea id="mensagemid" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem..." rows="6" maxlength="1300" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="Enviar()"/>
            </form>
        </section>
```

JS:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5500;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});

//Input submit onclick
function Enviar() {
    let nome = document.getElementById('nomeid');
    let email = document.getElementById('emailid');
    let assunto = document.getElementById('assuntoid');
    let mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagemid');
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            type: "login",
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
        },
    });
    
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'services.mail.sender@gmail.com',
        to: 'luciano.rocha.dev@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Static Resp Web - Nodemailer',
        text:
        `Nome: ${nome.value},
        E-mail: ${email.value},
        Assunto: ${assunto.value},
        Mensagem: ${mensagem.value}`
        //attachments: [ { filename: , path: , contentType: , } ]
    };
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
        } else {
            alert(`Obrigado ${nome.value}, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!`)
            console.log("E-mail enviado com sucesso.");
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using live-server on VS Code. I didn't find a state other than onclick for when the submit works after all the form is filled out correctly (html5 validation). My idea was to use this state to trigger the nodemailer function. Is there a better way to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The event you could use is a  `onsubmit`  HTML event attribute in the form. So after `name="form_contato"` place `onsubmit="Enviar()"`.

W3 has more information here if you need it, [Onsubmit HTML event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp). Then any validators you wanted could either be placed within the Enviar() function, or separately called in if you made each validation a function of its own.

There are other methods, like monitoring state, and setting global state in the window, but I am not sure if there are other factors involved? This would work for your purposes based on the code you provided though. I hope that this is helpful. Let me know if you have any questions. Happy Coding!

Comment: @LucianoRochaCunha Absolutely, let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by implementing Express to serve the static files of my page, and routing the Nodemailer for post requests (this in the server.js file). On the js client side, I got the form values, used preventDefault in the submit event, and sent AJAX request to server.js. After receiving the response, I issued a final alert to the user. I didn't need to use functions in the form's html.

app.js

```js
//Form Contato
    const contatoForm = document.querySelector('.form-contato');
    let nome = document.getElementById('nome');
    let email = document.getElementById('email');
    let assunto = document.getElementById('assunto');
    let mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem');
    let inputSubmit = document.getElementById('enviar');
    
    contatoForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        enviar.disabled = true;
    
        let formData = {
            nome: nome.value,
            email: email.value,
            assunto: assunto.value,
            mensagem: mensagem.value
        }
    
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if(xhr.responseText == 'success') {
                alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
                nome.value = '';
                email.value = '';
                assunto.value = '';
                mensagem.value = '';
            } else {
                alert('Algo deu errado...\n Comunique: luciano.rocha.dev2gmail.com')
            };
    
            enviar.disabled = false;
        };
    
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
```

server.js

```js
nst nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html')
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
            clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID,
            clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
        subject: `Static Resp Web - From ${req.body.nome}: ${req.body.assunto}`,
        text: 'De: ' + req.body.nome +
            '\nE-mail: ' + req.body.email +
            '\nAssunto: ' + req.body.assunto +
            '\nMensagem: ' + req.body.mensagem
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            // console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            // console.log('E-mail enviado: ' + info.response);
            res.send('success');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Thanks for all!